# RI doc error installing Rails with RVM on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

Installing Rails with RVM on Snow Leopard turned up this error during the installation of the RI docs:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
>     `undefined method`coverage_level=' for nil:NilClass

This occurred after installing the RI docs for railties-3.0.3.

I've done a search and didn't find anything similar. This is error isn't, perhaps, the end of the world, but I'd like to see if anyone has any ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2-p136 and RVM 1.2.0 on Mac OS 10.6.5. All of the Rails gems, besides the documentation, seemed, so far, to install fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was throwing the error during the documentation install for the gems. 
Using after the error => gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri rails 
Gave message => Successfully installed rails-3.0.3

Answer (score 2):

I get similar errors while installing other gems. Installing the newest rdoc gem helps sometimes, but not always.

Comment: Thank you. Well, it helps to know that at least other people are experiencing this problem and it's not the end of the world. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, although with different gems installed.

I tried to delete the gemset that was throwing the error and the confirmation message indicated asked if I wanted to delete another gemset. I deleted both gemsets and recreated them from scratch and I haven't see the error since.

In my case it looks like a problem with a duplicated gemset (rvm gemset copy source_gemset destination_gemset) was the problem.